# How to read and parse xml file present in azure data lake store using .NET?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I have few xml files in azure data lake store. i want to fetch those files from azure data lake and parse it.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I've performed this type of operation with a custom extractor. There were two parts to it: 1., A class that mapped the XML elements to properties using System.Xml.Serialization, and 2., The extractor method which creates an XmlSerializer object of that class type, and invokes the Deserialize method of that object over input.Basestream (the data). Finally, query with U-SQL using your custom extractor--which requires the library to be compiled, uploaded, registered, and, finally, referenced--before it is invoked with the USING statement of your query.

Part 1:

```
[XmlRoot("SomeRoot")]
public class MyDataClass
{
    [XmlElement("ELEMENT_0")]
    public Guid Column0 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ELEMENT_1")]
    public long Column1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ELEMENT_2")]
    public string Column2 { get; set; }     
}`enter code here`
```

Part 2:

```
[SqlUserDefinedExtractor(AtomicFileProcessing = true)]
public class Xml : IExtractor
{
    public override IEnumerable<IRow> Extract(IUnstructuredReader input, IUpdatableRow output)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyDataClass));

        MyDataClass data = (MyDataClass)ser.Deserialize(input.BaseStream);

        //blah blah

        output.Set<Guid>(0, data.Column0);
        output.Set<long>(1, data.Column1);
        output.Set<string>(2, data.Column2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Data Lake Store .NET SDK. Following tutorial walks you through on performing various file operations on files stored on Data Lake Store.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-net-sdk

Comment: I have gone through this link. I didn't give direct idea on how to parse a xml file which is present in azure data lake using .NET SDK. But I tried another approach, i read the data using StreamReader and created a new xml file locally then i used XML Document to parse the xml file. Once i have achieved my goal i deleted the locally created file using File.Delete.

Comment: I think you cannot do this using Data Lake .Net SDK until you download XML file and then parse it using any XML library. If you want to parse it without downloading then you can use XML Extractor and write USQL job to do this. See this: https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats

Comment: Same thing i mentioned in above comment. I don't want to use usql job to extract the xml data. I want to do that using .NET SDK.